# R: test_that multiple objects are equal

Tags: r, testing

I am trying to include a test using `testthat::test_that` in a script, and would like to write a test that multiple objects are equal:

```
dfX1 = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), 
                  x2 = rnorm(10), 
                  row.names = paste0("team", 1:10))

dfX2 = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), 
                  x2 = rnorm(10), 
                  row.names = paste0("team", 1:10))

dfX3 = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), 
                  x2 = rnorm(10), 
                  row.names = paste0("team", 1:10))

# something like this?
stopifnot(all(row.names(dfX1) == row.names(dfX2) == row.names(dfX3)))
```

I am fully aware that the last line makes no sense. I am looking for a compact solution that fits the `testthat` semantics.

Comment: Try `m1 <- sapply(mget(paste0('dfX', 1:3)), row.names); all(m1[,1]==m1)`

Comment: @akrun Thanks, as usual. :-) But the reason I asked explicitly for a solution that fits the `testthat` semantics is because I would like to make the tests readable, and as non-nested as possible.

Comment: I never used `testthat`.  But if there are say 100 datasets, `identical(row.names(dfX1),..` would mean a lot of typing. `all(Reduce(union,lapply(mget(paste0('dfX', 1:3)), row.names))==row.names(dfX1))`

Comment: But, if you check the output of that, it would be `FALSE` where as one in my comment gives `TRUE` or in the @grrgrrbla' post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
dfX1 = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), 
                  x2 = rnorm(10), 
                  row.names = paste0("team", 1:10))

dfX2 = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), 
                  x2 = rnorm(10), 
                  row.names = paste0("team", 1:10))

dfX3 = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), 
                  x2 = rnorm(10), 
                  row.names = paste0("team", 1:10))

# something like this?
stopifnot(identical(union(row.names(dfX1) ,row.names(dfX2)),
                row.names(dfX3)) == TRUE)
```

for more than 2 vectors use:

```
stopifnot(identical(Reduce(union, list(row.names(dfX1) ,row.names(dfX2),
row.names(dfX3, ... , row.names(dfX_Nminus1))),
                row.names(dfX_N)) == TRUE)
```

this also works, given that the length of all the vectors is equal:

```
l.d <- list(row.names(dfX1) ,row.names(dfX2),
        row.names(dfX3))
stopifnot(length(Reduce(intersect, l.d)) == length(l.d[[1]]))
```

Comment: I understand that this is an option, but I would like to list each of the items only once, since I will be building the list of objects programmatically.

Comment: Thanks. If I have greater than 3 objects, I will have to build a nested list. I am sure a solution exists this way as well, but I was really hoping for a `expect_equal(...)`.

Comment: if you have more than 3 objects you just type `is.identical(union(df1, df2, df3, ..., df_n.), df_n-1)` the union of all the other objects has to equal the last one.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with that for the time being. Will mark as accepted if nothing better shows up.

Comment: I was wrong union only works for 2 vectors, you would have to use this instead for the union of more than 2 vectors (example for 3 vectors x,y,z): `Reduce(union,  list(x,y,z))`

Answer (score 0):

## Two solutions with testthat:

```
library(testthat);library(purrr)
# example data
dfX1 = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), 
                  x2 = rnorm(10), 
                  row.names = paste0("team", 1:10))
dfX2 = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), 
                  x2 = rnorm(10), 
                  row.names = paste0("team", 1:10))
dfX3 = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), 
                  x2 = rnorm(10), 
                  row.names = paste0("team", 1:10))
```

#### Testthat solution 1 - does not identify where the problem is, but is a one-liner

```
expect_equal(unlist(unique(map(list(dfX1, dfX2, dfX3), row.names))), row.names(dfX1))
```

With error

```
olddfX3<-dfX3
row.names(dfX3) <- paste0(row.names(dfX3), 1)

expect_equal(unlist(unique(map(list(dfX1, dfX2, dfX3), row.names))), row.names(dfX1))
# Error: unlist(unique(map(list(dfX1, dfX2, dfX3), row.names))) not equal to row.names(dfX1).
# Lengths differ: 20 vs 10

dfX3<-olddfX3
```

#### Testthat solution 2 - 2x2 tests - will give you long error texts, but you can identify the problems

```
tests_2x2 <- function(names){

  lss <- setNames(lapply(names,get),names)
  
  len <- length(lss)
  
  
  for(x in 1:len){
    y=x+1
    while(y<=len){
      test_that(paste0("test that row.names(", 
        names(lss)[x], ") == row.names(", names(lss)[y], ")"), {
          expect_equal(row.names(lss[[x]]), row.names(lss[[y]]))})
      y=y+1
    }
  }
}
```

Input df names to get specific results on the tests

```
names<-c("dfX1", "dfX2", "dfX3")
tests_2x2(names)
```

One with error:

```
olddfX3<-dfX3
row.names(dfX3) <- paste0(row.names(dfX3), 1)
tests_2x2(names)
# Error: Test failed: 'test that row.names(dfX2) == row.names(dfX3)'
# * row.names(lss[[i]]) not equal to row.names(lss[[i + 1]]).
# 10/10 mismatches
# x[1]: "team1"
# y[1]: "team11"
# 
# x[2]: "team2"
# y[2]: "team21"
# 
# x[3]: "team3"
# y[3]: "team31"
# 
# x[4]: "team4"
# y[4]: "team41"
# 
# x[5]: "team5"
# y[5]: "team51"
# 
# x[6]: "team1"
# y[6]: "team11"
# 
# x[7]: "team2"
# y[7]: "team21"
# 
# x[8]: "team3"
# y[8]: "team31"
# 
# x[9]: "team4"
# y[9]: "team41"
# 
# x[10]: "team5"
# y[10]: "team51"
```